# Show the Lowest Tier Price of Grouped Product on List Page

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

The "FROM" price (on the Category List page) will correctly show the lowest price of a SIMPLE PRODUCT associated with the GROUPED product.

However, I am needing to show the Lowest TIER PRICE of the GROUPED Product on the Category List page.. because in reality.. this is the lowest price available to the customer for that product, and not the lowest Simple Product price as Magento calculates.

Can anyone help me with this please? I can get my way about phtml files etc but cannot work out how to achieve this.
Thank you very much for any support with this.

John.